# Creating a task scheduler

Tags: multithreading, winapi, mfc

i have a requirement to schedule recurrent tasks. My application is in MFC. For Eg I may need to send a file to a particular location on "From Date" "To Date" "Frequency" "Start Time" "End Time". i thought of having a list and add these parameters there and create a timer that elapses every second. Where i can check the list for the conditions and invoke the file transfer. But the problem is if the list is huge then i may not be able to do it. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use the system task scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Create a priority queue of scheduled events, and for each "schedule", fill the queue with only NEXT event for that "schedule".  Wait only for the first EVENT in the priority queue, and when used, look up into schedule item for that event, and let it fill its next event into the queue.

Please ask if anything above needs more clarification.

EDIT:

You'll trigger your event on the particular date and time depending what are you most comfortable with.  Since you'll have only ONE event that you'll have to wait for (you can copy it from the HEAD of the queue), you have multiple options, for example:

- SetTimer() for one second intervals, when compare current time with event time.
- SetTimer() for the duration of the current time to event time.
- start another thread, waitforsingleobject inside of it, with delay computed as eventi_time-now - this will be most difficult since you'll have to be careful when calling something on the main thread
- ... and so on

Comment: how to trigger the event on particular date & time?

Comment: Daniel thanks for your update, Bu the problem is there is not going to be only one event. I will have list of scheduled items.

Comment: Yes, and as I stated, you'll have your schedule list transform to the priority queue that will handle the rest.